# How to set a default value for a Flow type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have defined a custom Flow type

```
export type MyType = {
  code: number,
  type: number = 1,
}
```

I want the `type` parameter to default as `1` if no value is present. However, Flow is complaining with `Unexpected token =`.

[image: Flow error]

Can this be done with Flow?

Currently using Flow `v0.32.0`.

Comment: It's not possible. Moreover It doesn't make sense to mix and match types and values.

Comment: But it is possible to do this when annotating a function, i.e. `function (code: number, type: number = 1) {}`.

Comment: The `= 1` part is at the value level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have defaults in a type declaration.

## Possible idea

Use a class and initialise any defaults using property initialisers : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html#property-initializer

Answer (score 21):

Function parameters can also have defaults. This is a feature of ECMAScript 2015.

```
function method(value: string = "default") { /* ... */ }
```

In addition to their set type, default parameters can also be void or omitted altogether. However, they cannot be null.

```
// @flow
function acceptsOptionalString(value: string = "foo") {
  // ...
}

acceptsOptionalString("bar");
acceptsOptionalString(undefined);
acceptsOptionalString(null);
acceptsOptionalString();
```

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-function-parameters-with-defaults

Answer (score 6):

Go with the idea @basarat proposes, and use a class. A class exists as both a type and a value.

The value can be initialized. Flow recognizes a proposed property initializer syntax, so using Flow (for types) and babel (for proposed feature support) you can declare your class like [this](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBTAHgB1gJwC6gMbQCGAziaALICeAKlesqAN6KgGwAmyAXKAHYBXALYAjZFgDcrUDno9+wsVlABeUAEYpAXwlA):

```
// @flow
export class MyType {
  code: number;
  type: number = 1; 
};
```

Flow, and the types it lets you define, are not present in the javascript runtime. Thats why type declarations don't support value initializers.

Answer (score 0):

If setting it for a component then you can set a default value like so:

```
type Props = {
  code: number,
  type: number,
}

const Component = (props: Props) => (
  <div>{props.code}</div>
  <div>{props.type}</div>
);

// default values
const defaultProps: Props = {
  code: '',
  type: 1,
};

Component.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Component;
```